# Mounting Error at bootup

Tags: boot, fstab

How do I solve

> An error occurred while mounting /mnt/AA99-3674
>   keys:Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery"

Note: I have had this message at boot up for a while and I have not had any problems but now when I try to login my screen messes up and goes back to the login screen for every user account

The last 2 lines of the `/etc/fstab` is

> UUID=5400a303-8697-4819-8395-e93a4970ed6c none    swap sw   0    0
>   /dev/disk/by-uuid/AA99-3674, auto nosuid, nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

Comment: please post your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: please edit your question, and post the content of `/etc/fstab`. Don't try to post it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

locate the line relative to your **AA99-3674** drive and remove it. Then reboot.

Remember to make a backup copy of **/etc/fstab** before editing.

Comment: Now it says "The disk for nosuid, is not ready yet or not present"

Comment: Please, post the output of the following commands `fdisk -l` and `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Comment: You might need 'sudo fdisk -l'. I'm not an expert with fstab, but the second line looks peculiar to me. Entries in my fstab are of the form 'file system / mount point / type / options / dump / pass'. Could it be that the fstab entry is just plain wrong ? Do you know what type the partition really is ? (NTFS, ext4 etc)