# Cannot mount disks at bootup

Tags: mountpoint, udisks

I've been having a particular problem with Ubuntu and its flavours for a year. Now that I have made a fresh install of Xubuntu, I thought the problem might fix itself but it has not. Please keep in mind that I am a normal computer user. I have scoured the net for answers and simple solutions that my competence allows, I have tried.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40211/cannot-mount-disk-at-all-detailed-explanation-need-help) is very close to the problem I am having, although I can mount my disks once the OS has started if I click manually on them in Thunar or Nautilus. They are simply grayed out as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723871/mounting-error-at-bootup).

If I start GNOME Disks, the disks are found without a problem.

If you take a look at the settings, they should be correct. If I take away the automatic mount options at boot up, I get an error like:

```
An error occurred while mounting /mnt/*my disk name* keys:Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

...similar to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723871/mounting-error-at-bootup).

Here is my BIOS information, the BIOS sees the disks without a problems, and when I used to run windows, there never was a problem.

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 0809
    Release Date: 05/16/2014
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
    Characteristics:
            PCI is supported
            APM is supported
            BIOS is upgradeable
            BIOS shadowing is allowed
            Boot from CD is supported
            Selectable boot is supported
            BIOS ROM is socketed
            EDD is supported
            5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
            8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
            Serial services are supported (int 14h)
            Printer services are supported (int 17h)
            ACPI is supported
            USB legacy is supported
            BIOS boot specification is supported
            Targeted content distribution is supported
            UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6
```

As requested: 
The /etc/fstab contents when all disks are mounted (manually) are:
cat /etc/fstab

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2fc3dd54-6898-49f0-bd3d-40c9c822dd12 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7D71-BEB0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=43c256fc-2a8f-47ff-b6e5-77c6a2b68cbf none            swap    sw              0       0
```

***When not mounted are***

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2fc3dd54-6898-49f0-bd3d-40c9c822dd12 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7D71-BEB0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=43c256fc-2a8f-47ff-b6e5-77c6a2b68cbf none            swap    sw              0       0

<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2fc3dd54-6898-49f0-bd3d-40c9c822dd12 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7D71-BEB0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=43c256fc-2a8f-47ff-b6e5-77c6a2b68cbf none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I would really appreciate help.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your question to include the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: there seems to be a contradiction I do not get: if a partition is mounted as root, other as swap, who or what is mounting to  "../mnt/*my disk name* ..."   <br/>
  <br/>
Looks like some parts of /etc/fstab are missing here.    <br/>
what size is the disc?   why is the BIOS so old, any update possible? what does mount or /etc/mtab tell when  Gnome mounted  successful?  what rights (rwx) does /mnt have? what are the names of your mount points in /mnt? can you give a ls -latr of /mnt?